# Update an element of a template with a observable function

Tags: javascript, angular

How can i update an element of a template in a list with a function of type observable?

I'm going to show the code of what i'm trying to do.

This is the list, that has a date property:

```
     this.events.getItems({lang:this.idioma, date: "06/04/2018"})
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        this.currentEvents = data;
        this.loading.dismiss(); 
    })
```

this is the template:

```
    <ion-grid class="pad0A">
            <ion-row *ngFor="let event of currentEvents">
                <ion-col col-12 col-sm class="currentEventElem" [ngStyle]="{'background-image':currentBackground(event.image)}">
                    <h1>
                        {{event.title}}
                    </h1>
                    <h2 [innerHTML]="showDate(event?.data)">
                    </h2>
                </ion-col>
            </ion-row>
        </ion-grid>
```

And now the function:

```
showDate(date):Observable<string>{
    let dateNew = this.datePipe.transform(this.dateTimePipe.transform(date), "dd/MM/yyyy").split('/');
    return this.translate.get(this.getMonthByNumber(dateNew[1])).do(data => data);
}

getMonthByNumber(dayNumber){
    var day = "";
    if(dayNumber == "01")
        day = "Jan";
    else if(dayNumber == "02")
        day = "Feb";
    else if(dayNumber == "03")
        day = "Mar";
    else if(dayNumber == "04")
        day = "Apr";
    else if(dayNumber == "05")
        day = "May";
    else if(dayNumber == "06")
        day = "Jun";
    else if(dayNumber == "07")
        day = "Jul";
    else if(dayNumber == "08")
        day = "Aug";
    else if(dayNumber == "09")
        day = "Sep";
    else if(dayNumber == "10")
        day = "Oct";
    else if(dayNumber == "11")
        day = "Nov";
    else if(dayNumber == "12")
        day = "Dec";
    return day;
}
```

It appears [Object Object] inside h2 element.
I may be doing 2 or 3 ugly things, but how can i solve this in Angular?

Comment: Did you using `showDate(event?.data)|async` inside the innerHTML. using the `async` pipe.

Comment: Yes, that works. Nice

Comment: import { AsyncPipe } from '@angular/common';

Answer (score 2):

First, please, replace your method `getMonthByNumber()` by this one:

```
private months = [
    'Jan',
    'Feb',
    'Mar',
    'Apr',
    'May',
    'Jun',
    'Jul',
    'Aug',
    'Sep',
    'Oct',
    'Nov',
    'Dec',
];

private getMonthByNumber(dayNumber) {
    return months[dayNumber - 1];    
}
```

I don't think you have to use `innerHTML`, you could simply write this:

```
<h2>{{showDate(event.data)}}</h2>
```

The `?` in `event` can be safely removed.

Then you can use `translate.instant` instead of `translate.get` to avoid returning an observable.

Otherwise remove dead code `.do(data => data)` and use `async` pipe as follows:

```
showDate(date): Observable<string>{
    const dateNew = this.datePipe.transform(this.dateTimePipe.transform(date), "dd/MM/yyyy").split('/');
    return this.translate.get(this.getMonthByNumber(dateNew[1]));
}

<h2>{{showDate(event.data) | async}}</h2>
```

Comment: I need to use translate service because i have more than one language

Comment: I know, just replace `translate.get` by `translate.instant`. Then you will directly get a string instead of an observable. Otherwise use async pipe.